# What is the best method to analyze this standard example data

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons

The MASS package in R has 'anorexia' data set that compares the results of 3 treatments on weights of patients. Which statistical method is ideal to analyze this data set? There is one control (Cont) and 2 treatment groups (CBT and FT). The question being asked is which, if any, of the 2 treatments used is best for producing weight gain in patients with anorexia. The baseline weight (Prewt) could also influence the effect of treatment.

```
> library(MASS)
> data(anorexia)
> str(anorexia)
'data.frame':   72 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Treat : Factor w/ 3 levels "CBT","Cont","FT": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  $ Prewt : num  80.7 89.4 91.8 74 78.1 88.3 87.3 75.1 80.6 78.4 ...
 $ Postwt: num  80.2 80.1 86.4 86.3 76.1 78.1 75.1 86.7 73.5 84.6 ...
> head(anorexia)
  Treat Prewt Postwt
1  Cont  80.7   80.2
2  Cont  89.4   80.1
3  Cont  91.8   86.4
4  Cont  74.0   86.3
5  Cont  78.1   76.1
6  Cont  88.3   78.1
```

There is a method mentioned on this page: http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/demo.html . However, it is more for demonstration purpose rather than a recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seriously doubt there's any such thing as 'ideal' -- even what's 'good' depends on your criteria for goodness.

Some "classic" approaches to modelling this would be regression(/ANCOVA) with Prewt either as an offset or a covariate and Treat as the factor of interest, but perhaps the most common such approach would have not only Prewt as a predictor (covariate) but also the interactions with Treat in the model (so that different slopes as well as different intercepts could be considered).